# How beneficial is it to think in terms of relational algebra before writing SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

In a class on dbms we are taught to "make the solution in relational algebra" before converting to SQL. It really has become second nature and it's almost difficult to directly write SQL. Is this bad or good? I'm told it leads to better queries which is good but I can see a person getting fired quick if every time their asked to find something in a database they start writing math on a piece of paper.

Comment: If you do that enough, you will be able to do it in your head. Remember 3 hours of coding can save 2 minutes of planning which can save 10 seconds of discussion.

Comment: I think you have that backwards :p

Comment: Do what works for you.  I've sent fixed queries to coworkers before and included Jeff Moden's signature: "Stop thinking about what you want to do to a row... think, instead, of what you want to do to a 
column."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see someone getting fired for working out a solution to a problem before rushing into it?

It's always, always good to work out whatever you need to before coming up with a solution.  Over time, as your skill progresses, you'll find you don't need to prep as much.

Answer (score 3):

It is a good thing.

Too many programmers come to SQL without thinking relationally and end up using cursors and looping mechanism that are not suitable to SQL as relational databases are optimized for relational algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the point with relational algebra is that it's universal. It's not specific to one DBMS. So more people can understand it.

It might be more a theoretical stuff that you will see only at school and not really in practice but it's not a bad practice. It can help you before you start writing your query and consequently save time

I would be surprised if your boss fire you because you didn't do your relational algebra before your query or vice versa.

Also, some people use it to optimize their queries